# High Load - Low IO - Low CPU usage

Tags: performance, central-processing-unit, io

I have a system whose load is rather high.  As you can see from the top output below, CPU usage and I/O is negligible:

> top - 17:31:59 up 4 days,  2:34,  2
> users,  load average: 1.00, 0.99, 1.00
>
> Tasks:  71 total,   1 running,  70
> sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
>
> Cpu(s):  2.0%us,  2.0%sy,  0.0%ni,
> 95.9%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
>
> Mem:    960720k total,   707288k used,   253432k free,
> 67328k buffers
>
> Swap:  2811896k total,
> 2644k used,  2809252k free,   528928k
> cached
>
> PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT
> RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
>
> 15310 root      20   0  2512 1128  888
> R  2.1  0.1   0:00.05 top

I would appreciate any assistance with isolating the cause(s) of high load for when I/O and CPU are not factors.

Comment: run "vmstat 1" and "mpstat 1" to gather more info please

Comment: 0.70 is *not* a high load. What have you experienced that causes your view of a 'high load' on this server?

Comment: vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 0  0   2664 255272  67004 527560    0    0     0     0  315  224  0  0 100  0
 0  0   2664 255272  67004 527560    0    0     0     0  320  230  0  1 99  0
 0  0   2664 255264  67004 527560    0    0     0     0  322  223  0  0 100  0


mpstat

05:30:28 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
05:30:29 PM  all    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
05:30:30 PM  all    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.99    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.01

Comment: @Mikey
Client does not like the fact that their legacy software solution used less than 0.80 load on the exact same hardware/OS setup.  

Long term, the new software brings their system's load to just under 3.00.

No specific problem mentioned due to the high load, simply that they don't like the numbers they're seeing.

Of note, the new software is a multi-threaded app running on 5+ year single core system.

My main interest is grasping how the load can be above 1 when the CPU is idle, IO is dormant, and there remains plenty of memory?

Thanks...

Comment: @MikeyB
(please see previous comment)

Answer (score 5):

The high load can also be caused by a few factors:

- processes in "uninterruptible sleep" (`D` in the process list), that's processes waiting for some I/O.
- hardware issues, causing the system to wait for something (can be I/O).

Please check your process list (`ps auxf`), for any processes which may be in `D` state, or look weird.

Comment: - There are no  "D - Uninterruptible sleep" processes.
- I see no indication that I/O is the culprit (top, vmstat, mpstat).

Answer (score 2):

do

```
iostat -xk
iotop
```

check the await column. Most likely that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Issue appears to be due to a known issue with Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid).

[Bug Reference](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-ec2/+bug/574910)